# Bioinformatics script using Python/Biopython/Clustalw using stdout to iterate over a directory of proteins

Tags: python, stdout, bioinformatics, biopython

So I am doing a bit of bioinformatics work in python utilizing Biopython and Clustalw2 for aligning protein sequences. I am fairly new to this (only a couple months of experience) and I am running into a problem using stdout and iterating over an entire directory. Any help would be appreciated.

So I have written this, which handles one file at a time and produces the desired result...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import Bio
import os
from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalwCommandline
from Bio import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord


clustal_loc=r"/Users/Wes/Desktop/eggNOG_files/clustalw-2.1-macosx/clustalw2"
try:
    f_in=raw_input("Enter the filepath of the FASTA to align: ")
    f_out= raw_input("Enter the output filename: ")
    fh= open(f_in)
    fo=open(f_out,'w')
    for record in SeqIO.parse(fh,"fasta"):
            id = record.id
            seq = record.seq
            print("Name: %s, size: %s"%(id,len(seq)))
    try:
            cl = ClustalwCommandline(clustal_loc,infile=f_in, outfile=f_out, align=True, outorder="ALIGNED", convert=True, output="pir")
            assert os.path.isfile(clustal_loc), "Clustal W not found"
            stdout, stderr = cl()
            print cl
    except:
            print("There was a problem aligning. Check ClustalW path and .fasta input.")


    fh.close()
    fo.close()


except:
        print("Could not parse. Check to make sure filepath is correct and that file is in   FASTA format")
```

...And this seems to work just fine. The problem comes when I try to iterate this over an entire directory (like 1000+ files of protein sequences that need to be aligned. I know the problem is with stdout but I am a bit too amateur at this point to know how to fix it. Here is the broken code below —

```
/usr/bin/python

import Bio
import os
from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalwCommandline
from Bio import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
clustal_loc=r"/Users/Wes/Desktop/eggNOG_files/clustalw-2.1-macosx/clustalw2"

try:

    folder= raw_input("Enter the folder of .fasta files to iterate over and align: ")
    listing = os.listdir(folder)

    for infile in listing:
        print folder+'/'+infile
        f_in = open(folder+'/'+infile,'r')

        f_out=open(folder+'/'+infile+".pir",'w')


        for record in SeqIO.parse(f_in,"fasta"):
                id = record.id
                seq = record.seq
                print("Name: %s, size: %s"%(id,len(seq)))

        clustalw_cline= ClustalwCommandline(clustal_loc,infile=f_in, outfile=f_out, align=True, outorder="ALIGNED", convert=True, output="pir")

        assert os.path.isfile(clustal_loc), "Clustal W not found"
        saveout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = clustalw_cline()
        sys.stdout = saveout






        f_in.close()

        f_out.close()
except:
    print("There was a problem aligning. Check ClustalW path and .fasta folder format/location")
```

As you can see I have been mucking this one up pretty badly. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: you could also ask biostar: http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: Where you construct the ClustalwCommandline object, the infile and outfile argument should be filenames as strings - not file objects. I'd write more here but the comments don't let me do code formatting...

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error you are seeing? You shouldn't set sys.sterr and sys.stdout to string values (the clustalw_cline() function returns the clustal stderr and stdout as strings), as you won't be able to write anything to stdout from python.

I tried to clean up and correct your code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Bio
import os
from glob import glob
from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalwCommandline
from Bio import Seq
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
clustal_loc=r"/Users/Wes/Desktop/eggNOG_files/clustalw-2.1-macosx/clustalw2"

try:
    folder= raw_input("Enter the folder of .fasta files to iterate over and align: ")
    listing = glob(os.path.join(folder, '*.fasta'))
    for infile in listing:
        print infile
        with open(os.path.splitext(infile) + '.pir') as f_out:
            with open(infile) as f_in:
                for record in SeqIO.parse(infile,"fasta"):
                        id = record.id
                        seq = record.seq
                        print("Name: %s, size: %s"%(id,len(seq)))
                assert os.path.isfile(clustal_loc), "Clustal W not found"
                clustalw_cline= ClustalwCommandline(clustal_loc,infile=f_in,
                                                    outfile=f_out, align=True, 
                                                    outorder="ALIGNED",convert=True, output="pir")
                stdout, stderr = clustalw_cline()
except Exception:
    print("There was a problem aligning. Check ClustalW path and .fasta folder format/location")
```

Comment: Well I am trying to write the alignment produced by clustalw to a .pir file. The first script seems to handle this for a single file just fine. Are you saying I should ditch the stdout and stderr? When I do this, the original script that handles a single file does not work properly. Thank you for the cleanup and help.

Comment: In your first script, the stdout and stderr variables are catching the output of clustal as strings. In your second script, you are assigning the python file-like object sys.stdout to the output of clustalw_cline(), which is a tuple of the form (stdout, stderr), which is almost certainly not what you want to do. If you want to write the clustalw output to sys.stdout, you should either use the print function, or use sys.stdout.write(output)

Comment: I just want to write the clustalw_cline() output to the file that I have opened i.e. f_out... but I can't seem to do it this time around.